# Django - Cannot get console.log to output in VSCode Terminal

Tags: javascript, django

I'm new to using Javascript with django and am trying to use console log to test my Javascript code but am having trouble getting it to work. I check the terminal, outpout, problems, and Debug console but none show the output of console.log. I know my javascript is working because the ui dropdown menu is populated when I use the ajax code below and it displays nothing if I remove it. However, I cannot tell if the event listener is working..

here is my html:

```
<div class="ui selection dropdown" id = "cars">
    <input type="hidden" name="car">
    <i class="dropdown icon"></i>
        <div class="default text">Choose a car</div>
            <div class="menu" id = 'cars-data-box'>

            </div>
</div>
```

Here is my Javascript

```
const carsDataBox = document.getElementById('cars-data-box')
const carInput = document.getElementById('cars')

$.ajax({
type: 'GET',
url: '/cars-json/',
success: function(response){
    console.log(response)
    const carsData = response.data
    carsData.map(item=>{
        const option = document.createElement('div')
        option.textContent = item.name
        option.setAttribute('class', 'item')
        option.setAttribute('data-value', item.name)
        carsDataBox.appendChild(option)
    })
},
error: function(error){
    console.log(error)
}
```

})

```
carInput.addEventListener('change', e=>{
    const selectedCar = e.target.value
    console.log(response)
    })
```

urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
path('', page),
path('cars-json/', get_json_car_data),
]
```

views.py

```
def page(request):
    qs = Car.objects.all()
    return render(request, 'testenv/home.html', {'qs' : qs})

def get_json_car_data(request):
    qs_val = list(Car.objects.values())
    return JsonResponse({'data' : qs_val})
```

Comment: Check your chrome/firefox developer console and use ```console.log``` there!

Comment: Thanks so much, that helped! is there anyway to see it in VSCode as well?

Comment: im sure there is, I just haven't done it myself!

Comment: No worries, this works good enough!